# I have image hosting site, I want to redirect those visitors who try to open image directly to the content page

Tags: html, .htaccess, redirect

There are many images uploading daily, so its not easy to update manually .htaccess each hour. So please tell me the way i can redirect each visitor to content page who try to access my images directly.

Comment: Maybe with .htaccess rules?

Comment: Best chance is to check the referrer header, but users don't have to send this to you, so you can never be sure if you are being hotlinked.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done only by checking `HTTP_REFERER` header. Though keep in mind that `HTTP_REFERER` can also be manipulated.

Try this rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$ 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?localhost/ [NC] 
RewriteRule \.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png)$ /content-page [L,NC,R]
```

Comment: thanks but its not working for me, Here is example which i want to add in my site : when visitor open http://www.livememe.com/36opcf5.jpg he redirects to http://www.livememe.com/36opcf5

Comment: You need to replace `localhost` by your domain name and replace `content-page` with your actual page name.

Comment: dear still its not working. Actualy i have image hosting site and there are more than 1000 images and most of them are hotlinked. Now the probleme is that I have advertises on my site but they are worthless if they are not displaying. So i want to show ads arround images even when some one try to see the images directly. Now you have the full matter what i actually want. Do you have any solution ? It will be very helpful for me

Comment: Can you place your latest and full .htaccess in your question? btw this is working code from my live blog site.

Comment: If you want to wrap some code around those images then you can place custom ad display code in the `/content-page` to show ads and images both.

Comment: I already put advertises on my page but it shows only when full url is entered i.e. with html page, but obviously ads will not shown when image url is directly entered i.e. ending with someimage.jpg its not allowing me to past full .htaccess because error showing its too long

Comment: You can just comment out both `RewriteCond` for testing and then it will execute `/content-page` unconditionally.

Answer (score 0):

You cant do it, because there is no difference for `apache` between calling a url directly, or put that url in the `src` attribute of an `img` tag .

and, because of that, `.htaccess` cant do such thing .

Comment: I saw that on many site here is example : when we try to open http://www.livememe.com/36opcf5.jpg we can see http://www.livememe.com/36opcf5 i want the same thing as it is

Comment: right click on the image and select view image, it will show the image

Comment: but do you know how to redirect in the same way as i mentioned in example in previous comment ?

Comment: put your img in a `a` tag with `href='somewhere.php'`. and do not show the image in the `somewhere.php`